# Setter but not for Style in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I know how Triggers with Setters work in WPF, and I know that Setters can only change Style properties. Is there something equivalent to the Setter for non-Style properties? I really want to be able to change a property on custom object that is instantiated in XAML. Any ideas?

**Edit:** While Setters can update any dependency property, I am attempting to do this within an EventTrigger, which I forgot to specify. There is [this](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/event-based-property-changes) workaround, but I'm not sure if it is really best practice. It uses storyboards and ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames. Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Setters are not actually for Style properties only. They can change any `DependencyProperty`, whether it is used in style or not.

Comment: @Fyodor Soikin: That asker probably meant DependencyProperties and wants to set a normal CLR property.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, but does it work for you own object? Are its properties animatable and DependencyProperties?

Comment: @HB- Nope, you are correct. All I'm really trying to do is change a public int property on a xaml instantiated object when an event fires. I could do it easily in the code behind, but I would prefer to do it in Xaml if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Interactivity` from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=f1ae9a30-4928-411d-970b-e682ab179e17&displaylang=en) you can do this in XAML, you only need to create a `TriggerAction` which sets the property.

---

**Edit:** There already is such an action in another namespace: [`ChangePropertyAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.interactivity.core.changepropertyaction%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

In XAML you can use this namespace: `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions`

---

Tested example:

```
public class PropertySetterAction : TriggerAction<Button>
{
    public object Target { get; set; }
    public string Property { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        Type type = Target.GetType();
        var propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(Property);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(Target, Value, null);
    }
}
```

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <obj:Employee x:Key="myEmp" Name="Steve" Occupation="Programmer"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEmp}, Path=Name}"/>
        <Run Name="RunChan" Text=" - "/>
        <Run Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEmp}, Path=Occupation}"/>
    </TextBlock>
    <Button Content="Demote">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <t:PropertySetterAction Target="{StaticResource myEmp}"
                                        Property="Occupation"
                                        Value="Coffee Getter"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Note that with `Value` being an object default ValueConversion will not take place, if you enter a value as an attribute (`Value="Something"`) it will be interpreted as a string. To set an `int` for example you can do this:

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

```
<t:PropertySetterAction Target="{StaticResource myEmp}"
                        Property="Id">
    <t:PropertySetterAction.Value>
        <sys:Int32>42</sys:Int32>
    </t:PropertySetterAction.Value>
</t:PropertySetterAction>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the properties that you want to set as dependency properties?  I can't find the project I did this in, but I am pretty sure that is what fixed it for me.

I tried implementing something pretty simple, and got the following:
The property "Type" is not a DependancyProperty.  To be used in markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type with and accessible instance property "Type".  For attached properties the declaring type must provide static "GetType" and "SetType" methods.

Here is a dependancy property registration example from another project of mine:

```
 Public Shared TitleProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", GetType(String), GetType(SnazzyShippingNavigationButton))
```

In the above example, SnazzyShippingNavigationButton is the Class Name of which the property is a member.

And the associated property declaration:

```
<Description("Title to display"), _
 Category("Custom")> _
Public Property Title() As String
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(TitleProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        SetValue(TitleProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property
```

Description and Category attributes only really apply to the IDE designer property grid display.